# How to run macro continuously?

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel sheet, i have a dynamic data getting updated every second and in this sheet I want column U to get sorted in descending order so as the corresponding columns. I found a workaround where I placed the below code in Module and I have to "Run Sub(F5)" each time when I want the column U sorted in descending order.

Now my question is how can I make this "Run Sub(F5)" run automatically.

This is my code.

```
Sub sortononecol()
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=Range("U1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by continuously? You need to be more precise. Please [edit] your original question and give an example.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the worksheet's code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U:U")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo meh
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=Range("U1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    End If

meh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Since your primary sort key is column U, a re-sort should only be necessary when a value in column U is deleted, added or modified.

Comment: Unless column U contains a formula referencing another sheet or workbook...  `Application.OnTime` is another option, but a *messy* one, and you need to remember to disable it when you close the workbook too.